# How to start deluge minimised, only with a tray (notification area) icon?

Tags: notification-area, deluge

I would like Deluge to start upon each startup, so I put deluge-gtk in Startup Applications. Now there is the window appearing each time, and I would like that it starts minimised, only with the notification area icon. Is there a way to do that?

Seems that before it could be set in the Preferences, and there was also a command line string to do it, but these features are gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

If you start deluge from command  line it will start in the tray.

Answer (score 3):

The option is still there in the preferences, and works perfectly (tested with Ubuntu 11.04 classic gnome):

Interface page, System Tray section: Start in tray.